# How do I protect the stored clients' public keys on a server?

Tags: databases, server

I'm learning about security at the moment, and I want to store my clients' public keys on the server to facilitate distributing and managing those keys, my question is what are the possible ways to protect those keys when they are stored in the server from manipulating by attackers?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a number of issues such as how they are used, what the architecture of the server is, etc. But a few ideas to think about are:

- can you store them on a 'write only' medium? A 'finalised' CD-ROM for example?
- can you check their fingerprints before use against a copy of the fingerprints stored on a different server, or downloaded from a (trusted) public key server?
- can you download the keys from a (trusted) public key server before each use (check the security of the connection to the key server, including DNS records resolving to the server before use)?
- can you enter the fingerprint for the keys ephemerally at boot time and then compare them against the computed fingerprint at the time of use?
- have you got file integrity software running that you can trust? If not, I'd consider this option very strongly because you may be able to trust the keys, but if the rest of the system is compromised why is that any use?

PKI is a 'solved problem' to some extent so have you also looked at commercial solutions to this everyday problem?

Comment: Could you please describe the following point in more details:

can you enter the fingerprint for the keys ephemerally at boot time and then compare them against the computed fingerprint at the time of use

Comment: You would need a service that starts at boot time and requires a user to type in the fingerprints for the keys you are protecting. The fingerprints wouldn't be written to disk but kept in memory (therefore difficult to change during an attack - though not impossible obviously) and the system using the keys would query this service for the fingerprints entered at boot time and compare them with the fingerprints for the stored keys. The term 'ephemeral' in this instance just means that the values don't survive a reboot because they are only every stored in memory.